# SocketTimeout on Java 11 but not on Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, okhttp, java-11

I have a very weird behavioural difference when my Java program is run with Java 8 and Java 11.

I am using the MSGraph API (1.7.0) to make several calls to the Onedrive APIs. To make these calls, I am using 4 parallel threads for sync a lot of files (around 1000) on my hard disk.

When I execute the program with Java 8, I get no exceptions. When I execute it with java 11, I get a Socket Timeout Exception in around the 60% of the calls.

To configure the `IGraphServiceClient`, I am using the default configuration. As far as I am concerned, the HTTP Provider is OKHttp3 in this case.

Has anybody experienced anything like this?

**[UPDATE-1]**

These are the environments I have tested:

- Oracle's JDK 1.8.0_192 --> Perfect. Not an error in around 400 calls
- Openjdk 11.0.7 and Oracle's jdk 11.0.3 --> tons of Sokcet Timeout Exceptions

Hereby you have the stacktrace:

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:422) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseStreamRequest.send(BaseStreamRequest.java:85) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DriveItemStreamRequest.get(DriveItemStreamRequest.java:55) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveServiceClient.download(OnedriveServiceClient.java:236) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveFile.download(OnedriveFile.java:42) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.model.wrapper.RemoteFile.download(RemoteFile.java:20) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.task.LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.downloadIntoTemp(LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.java:71) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.task.LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.execute(LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.java:54) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.Syncer.lambda$taskRunner$1(Syncer.java:66) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:656) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:664) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:153) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:131) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:35) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:356) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 15 more
```

and a second stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:656) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:664) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSource.read(Http2Stream.java:398) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec$StreamFinishingSource.read(Http2Codec.java:205) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:439) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[?:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveServiceClient.download(OnedriveServiceClient.java:239) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveFile.download(OnedriveFile.java:42) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 9 more
```

**[UPDATE-2]**

After overriding the okhttp dependency to versions 3.14.9 and 4.7.2 (latest available), everything is still the same, although something has changed. Besides the usual timeout exception:

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:422) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseStreamRequest.send(BaseStreamRequest.java:85) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DriveItemStreamRequest.get(DriveItemStreamRequest.java:55) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveServiceClient.download(OnedriveServiceClient.java:236) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveFile.download(OnedriveFile.java:42) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.model.wrapper.RemoteFile.download(RemoteFile.java:20) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.task.LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.downloadIntoTemp(LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.java:71) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.task.LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.execute(LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.java:54) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.Syncer.lambda$taskRunner$1(Syncer.java:66) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:677) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.kt:686) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:143) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:96) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:35) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:356) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 15 more
```

a new one appears from time to time:

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:422) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:204) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:184) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseStreamRequest.send(BaseStreamRequest.java:85) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DriveItemStreamRequest.get(DriveItemStreamRequest.java:55) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveServiceClient.download(OnedriveServiceClient.java:236) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.provider.onedrive.OnedriveFile.download(OnedriveFile.java:42) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.model.wrapper.RemoteFile.download(RemoteFile.java:20) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.task.LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.downloadIntoTemp(LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.java:71) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.task.LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.execute(LocalFileDownloadSyncTask.java:54) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at easybox.syncing.Syncer.lambda$taskRunner$1(Syncer.java:66) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:148) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:96) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:35) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:356) ~[easybox-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: What happens if you run your code outside of eclipse with Java 8?

Comment: Java 8 to Java 11 is a big change. Many standard libs were broken out into separate packages that must be imported. It's likely the Timeouts are masking some other error from a missing library. Paste you stack trace so we can help.

Comment: @AlexR, it works perfectly. Indeed I updated the title. The problem is not anymore the environment (Eclipse or CLI), but the Java version I use to run the program

Comment: @SnakeDoc, question updated and stack trace added

Comment: It looks like the culprit is OkHttp: whatever version of OkHttp3 MSGraph uses appears to have some compatibility issue with Java 11.  It's interesting that OpenJdk 11 and Oracle Jdk 11 both show the same behavior.  Q: Is there any chance you can change the OkHttp3 timeout in your code?  For example, set it to "0"?

Comment: @FoggyDay, actually I tried it. Luckily enough the graph SDK exposes the Http Provider and you can configure it. I did not set to 0, actually, but to 60 seconds (both connectionTimeout and readTimeout). The same thing happens (just after 60 seconds). Interesting fact is that monitoring the network interface I can clearly see packets coming in from Microsoft servers......

Comment: Are you using Maven for dependency resolution and stuff? Looks like MSGraph has a dependency on Graph Core 1.0.0, which has a dependency on OKHttp 3.12.1. You can try overriding the OKHttp 3.12.1 import by manually specifying it in your POM and select a more updated version. See if that helps... According to Square's page on OKHttp, 3.12.x is LTS for Java 7+, which means it depends on features that were externalized in Java 9 and above. They even have a bugfix in 3.14.8 which prevents crashing for Java 8u252+ that deals with backported API changes from Java9

Comment: It is vanishinlgy unlikey that a timeout exception is 'masking some other error from a missing library'. @SnakeDoc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OkHttp on JDK9 (or JDK8 252+), will negotiate HTTP/2 by default.  There is a high chance it is related to this change.

Try building a client without HTTP/2 and see if you still get this problem.

```
  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
      .build()
```

If it fixes things, it's likely either an incompatibility of the server with HTTP/2, or related to connection reuse e.g. too many requests over a single connection.

UPDATE by kekolab 20201030.

Microsoft fixed the issue by restraining the protocol version to 1.1, exactly as suggested by the OP Yuri above. Nice stuff, this thread is referenced in the code: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/pull/473/files#

Comment: mmm... will give it a try... Actually, the creation of the OKHttp Client is quite buried in the SDK, so it will take me some time (if I decide to do so, actually... it's a personal project. I could just decide I am lazy enough to keep it running on Java 8 :D)

Comment: nailed it! I put a brakepoint where the client is created and altered the list of protocols removing HTTP2. Now the problem is how to override it in the buried Microsoft SDK.

Comment: The bug file to Microsoft (not mine) about all the exceptions of graph APIs: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/313
In the comments, my first reply (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/313#issuecomment-635664791) where I report @yuri-schimke's analysis and a second post where I exaplain the difficulties to use an alternative client (Apache Commons HttpClient) and how I circumvented the problem by imposing an HTTP1/1 only OKHttpClient (although with reflection): https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/313#issuecomment-636532884

Comment: Suggested solution is committed https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/commit/2f082f59b9f2aef87e540931595dc128c9ce4f8b  - after upgrade - we still continue to receive "SocketException: socket closed" errors.  Any clue?   @kekolab

Comment: Hopefully after next OkHttp this can be reverted - tracking bug in the SDK https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core/issues/88

Answer (score 2):

The OKHttp version you are using is incompatible with Java 11 (Java 9 and above actually).

[Microsoft Graph 1.7.1 has a dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph/1.7.1) of [Microsoft Graph Core 1.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.graph/microsoft-graph-core/1.0.0), which has a dependency on [OKHttp version 3.12.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/3.12.1).

According to [Square's changelog for OKHttp, 3.12.x is a LTS version for Java 7+](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3130). This means it will expect certain packages/modules and class names to exist, which may not after Java 9 and above (more below).

[Version 3.14.8 introduced some fixes for Java 9 API changes that break OKHttp.](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3148)

You should manually specify this version of OKHttp in your POM, or include this Jar to override the older version's implicit dependency.

As an aside, this is a common issue when porting things from Java 8 to Java 9 and above. [Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) broke out many components of the bloated JDK into modules. Many of the "enterprise" features that made the JDK so large were separated into their own modules, which you must specify to include in your project. Many libraries from the Java 8 days and older expect these modules to still exist "out of the box", which leads to strange failures like what you are seeing - but more commonly the infamous `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: OkHttp releases are strongly backwards compatible. You shouldn't need to pin to an old version, and if doing so helps please open a bug!

Comment: @JesseWilson OP can use any newer version of OKHttp, so long as it works with their original requirement of Microsoft Graph. I was pointing out the default version is not just outdated, it's probably going to have problems with Java 11, given the clear bugfix line item.

Comment: yes, I am using a dependency management tool (Gradle, actually). I will give it a try tonight (I hope I have time tonight) and will let you know whether everything still works (and eventually works better) after overriding the implicit MSGraph dependency.

Comment: @SnakeDoc, alas we were not lucky (please see UPDATE-2 in the original question). I think I will file two bug reports to Microsoft and to OKhttp, I think